# For Loop Not Terminating with Null Terminator

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am working on a machine problem and was tasked to input *'n'* arrays that I will then have to “merge sort”.

However, when I execute and input the words, it won't stop at the *'nth'* word and will ask me to input more characters even when I made use of a null terminator.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mp1_lib.h"

int main()
{
    int n;      
    printf("\n");
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n += 1;
    char words[n][16];
    initialize(n, words);
    get_words(n, words);
    print_words(n, words);  
    printf("\n");
}

void initialize(int n, char words[][16])
{  
    for (int x=0; x < n; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
        {
            words[x][y] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void get_words(int n, char words[][16])
{
    char c;
    char check = '0';
    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        int y = 0;
        while (check != '\0' && y < 16)
        {
            c = getchar();
            words[x][y] = c;
            check = c;
            y++;
        }
    }
}

void print_words(int n, char words[][16]) 
{
    for(int x=0; x < n; x++)
    {   
        for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
        {   
            putchar(words[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you inputing a null char in the keyboard? Have you tried `while (check != '*' && y < 16)` just to see if * char input will exit the loop?

Comment: yes! that worked :) not the '\0' though

Comment: What does your debugger say? Where exactly does it go wrong? Debugging is a major part of programming, get used to it.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you need to write prototypes for your functions, or put the `main` function at the very end.

Comment: @Bel well, that probably is because you cannot directly type a null character (or you were not inputing a null character).

Comment: Don't read strings char by char with `getchar()` but use `fgets` or `scanf`

Comment: @Bel What is your `check != '\0'` supposed to do ? What are you typing that could result in getchar() returning a 0 byte ?

Comment: Hello! My debugger is not detecting any syntax error.

Comment: If I were to use fgets or scan in my code how should my codes look like?

Comment: I'm so sorry if I seem really clueless. I just started coding functions in C and have a long way to go. I hope you can all understand and be patient with me. Thank you again for doing your best to help me :)

Comment: @Bel: debuggers aren't used for finding syntax errors. They allow you to watch your program as it executes, stepping through the program a line at a time, watching the values of variables, etc.

Comment: If you are using some crap C90 compiler, then all manner of interesting bugs could spawn if you have no function prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Since typing a null character can be tricky for the end user, I suggest you change your line to check for other character like an escape character or <kbd>ESC</kbd> key which value is 27 and it is easier to type

```
while (check != 27 && y < 16)
```

Comment: Maybe not portably, but for example on Ubuntu it's perfectly possible: use Ctrl-@ or Ctrl-space. But it's a very odd input convention, so I agree with the suggestion to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enter a `'\0'`-character, which is the same as value `0` or `0x0`, through the keyboard. Hence, your loop will not terminate this way.

Usually, when getting input through the keyboard, you will terminate a single string by pressing "enter", represented by the new line character `'\n'` then.
You could further enhance your program to stop scanning words once an "empty" word is entered, i.e. the length of the word is 0.
See the following program, which makes use of `fgets` for reading in a string until the next new line character + a common code to remove the new line character itself then:

```
void get_words(int n, char words[][16])
{
    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        if (fgets(words[x],16,stdin)){
            words[x][strcspn(words[x],"\n")] = '\0';  // remove new line (if any)
        }
        else{
            words[x][0] = '\0';  // othwise, set it to an empty string
            break;
        }
        if (words[x][0] == '\0')  // empty string entered (or end-of-file reached)
            break;
    }

}

void print_words(int n, char words[][16])
{
    for(int x=0; x < n && words[x][0] != '\0'; x++)  {
        printf("%s\n",words[x]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("\n");

    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    n += 1;

    char words[n][16];

    get_words(n, words);

    print_words(n, words);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Note further that your `initialize`-function does not terminate the strings; This will lead to undefined behaviour once you access the strings then using, for example, with `printf`.

Suggestion:

```
void initialize(int n, char words[][16])
{  
    for (int x=0; x < n; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < 16; y++)
        {
            words[x][y] = ' ';
        }
        words[x][16-1] = '\0';
    }
}
```